# Why I cannot initialize an array with pointters?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have tried to understand the connection between pointers and arrays. Why this prints `"okkoD@@"`? Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char a = 'o';
    char b = 'k';
    char uga[2];
    *(uga) = a;
    *(uga+1) = b;
    printf("%s", uga);
}
```

Comment: The `printf()` expects `uga[]` to be a `'\0'` terminated string.  So you need to make `uga[]` at least one longer and add a `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because a string in C is terminated by 0. So when you do this `printf("%s", uga);` the function will print the characters until it find the 0 element, then it stops. But there is none in `uga`, so it will keep printing characters from the stack. It is an undefined behavior. Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char a = 'o';
    char b = 'k';
    char uga[3];
    *(uga) = a;
    *(uga+1) = b;
    *(uga+2) = 0; // adding string terminating 0
    printf("%s", uga);
}
```